# Disable a button while using action_button in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add a html *disable* attribute while using action_button, in rails view,  something similar to this :

```
<div class="column-2">
   <% if action? %>
     <%= action_button :secondary, 
         I18nt("btn_amend"),
         {:id => 'amend_staging_date',
          :class => "",
          :disabled: true } %>
     <% end %>
 </div>
```

Even after adding the *disabled* attribute, the button is still not disabled.

Comment: Is action_button a custom plugin?

Comment: Yes, it is. https://github.com/brianjlandau/action_button

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this plugin. However, I see a typo in your code.

You had mentioned `:disabled: true` it should be `:disabled => true` or `disabled: true`

Here is the fixed version

```
<div class="column-2">
<% if action? %>
 <%= action_button :secondary, 
     I18nt("btn_amend"),
     {:id => 'amend_staging_date',
      :class => "",
      :disabled => true } %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```